# Linq to sql - database won't update

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I can't insert record to table

```
PODataContext db = new PODataContext();

test t = new test();
t.name = "name";
t.age = "dfd";

db.tests.InsertOnSubmit(t);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

My application is running perfectly. but inserted record is not there. But When I read from db it is working perfectly.

```
var s = from n in db.tests
        select n;

foreach(var k in s)
{
    MessageBox.Show(k.name);
}
```

Why is that ? (I have installed VS 2010 only) Please Help .!!

Thank You

Comment: Is it possible the connection string used in the `PODataContext` is not pointing to the same database you are looking at?

Comment: 'inserted record is not there'? Where is the inserted record not? You go on to state that the record is in the database so where is the record not appearing that you expect it to?

Comment: Are you actaully saying that the record is inserted, but your `DataContext` isn't showing the newly inserted record?

Comment: Check the database to see if the record has been added.

Comment: that's what I am saying. Record I am trying is not going to database :(

Comment: After refreshing the table, do you NEVER see any changes?

Comment: exactly. after refreshing nothing happened. no changes

Comment: This might no help much, but please try following: PODataContext db = new PODataContext(" check and add connection string here! "); Table<test> t = db.GetTable<test>(); t.InsertOnSubmit(test); db.SubmitChanges();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure what your table has Primary Key

Comment: I'm pretty sure an exception would be thrown if there is an issue like this.

Comment: Sadly, no. It doesn't throw an exception. Just ran into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the `DataContext` cache using the following:

```
db.GetType().InvokeMember(
    "ClearCache",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
    null, db, null);
```

This may resolve your issue.  Also, if you are using `Refresh()` this won't get the latest changes from the database.

Comment: @leo87: Sorry, that should have been `db`.  Have amended answer now.